# Cache the user identity

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

There is any way to cache the identity? In my code, I have multiple DB queries about user profile. I think should be a way to cache it to prevent multiple requests.

```
yii::$app->user->identity
```

Answer (score 0):

Identity should already be cached in context of request (only one query per request).

If you want to cache identity between requests, you can implement caching in [`findIdentity()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-identityinterface#findIdentity()-detail) implementation of class used as [`$identityClass`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#$identityClass-detail) of your `user` component:

```
public static function findIdentity($id) {
    return static::find()->cache(60)->where(['id' => $id])->one();
}
```

But usually it is not worth the trouble - one simple query using primary key should be really fast, caching it will not give you measurable performance boost, while it may create some weird cache-related bugs.